# Syntax error when executing OPENROWSET Command

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SET @fullPath = 'D:\Hosting\Project\Content\Order\ImportTest.txt'

SET @command = N'select @data_count =(select len(BulkColumn) - len(replace(BulkColumn, 
char(10), '')) + 1
from OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @fullPath + ''',
SINGLE_CLOB) ROW_SET'

EXEC(@command)
```

The commands above are generating the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Incorrect syntax near 'D:'.
>
> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ', SINGLE_CLOB) ROW_SET'.

How do I fix the above issue?

Comment: _How do I fix the above issue?_ You can't fix what you cannot see. To debug dynamic sql you must print or select the string that your code generates so you can actually examine the query, see the incorrect syntax, and then fix your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you escaped the single quotes in `BULK ''' + @fullPath + '''` you have to do it here: `char(10), ''''`.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the double-quotes, you also need to *properly* escape the filename using `QUOTENAME`

```sql
SET @fullPath = 'D:\Hosting\Project\Content\Order\ImportTest.txt';

SET @command = N'
select
  @data_count = len(BulkColumn) - len(replace(BulkColumn, char(10), '''')) + 1
from OPENROWSET(BULK ' + QUOTENAME(@fullPath, '''') + ',
              SINGLE_CLOB) ROW_SET
';

EXEC sp_executesql @command;
```